# Developing a SECURE PHP online-editor with Preview

Tags: php, editor

basically you could give a user a texarea, than onsubmit load and execute the client-written code in a preview frame.

the problem is here about security. the client could use it as a mailspammer, view/download all the directories/files and lot of other more dangerous things.

my question is if there is a class already written which prevents the use of certain dangerous functions and constants??

or

what smart ways you would suggest preventing abuse of such a tool?

PS: here is a sample already doing this http://codepad.org/

Comment: i want to do it .. if it is possible to do it safely. thats why i am here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php

You can pass in disable_functions, a "Comma separated list of functions to disable within the sandbox sub-interpreter."

Comment: hi. i know this. the question is which functions to take into. this must have been done before from other's i guess. its really tricky to select the functions. i am also thinking about disabling some functions to some extend (disabling them but rebuilding them with a custom function with limited scope). thx for the link